# What does "..."[] mean in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to configure webpack. When I configure the `module.rules`, I checked the `types.d.ts` to see `rules` definition. And I see this words:

```
/**
 * An array of rules applied for modules.
 */
rules?: (RuleSetRule | "...")[];
```

And I want to know what does `"..."[]` mean in Typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RuleSetRule` [is an object](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/types.d.ts#L8122):

```
declare interface RuleSetRule {
    /**
     * Match the child compiler name.
     */
    compiler?:
        | string
        | RegExp
        | {
   ... lots of lines
```

And `"..."` is a plain string type. By enclosing these in parentheses and alternating between them with `|`, you get a type that matches either one or the other (either the object or the string). Putting `[]` after it results in a type of an *array* of those.

For example:

```
const foo = [
  '...',
  { compiler: 'abc' /* other properties */ },
  '...'
];
```

would match that type.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsoF4oG8pgBOcYAXFAM7CECWAdgOZQC+A3AFCiSyIQCChQtigAKeEjSYAPlABEAOkWyAlAG0AuhwDGcOlSgBDQeXH9Bw1eyjW8BYmSgByAG4GANo5YAaKzceL5Rx8bWyISckcKXmAAC3omCDcKaEdmdnUgA) of an example.

Comment: So I can relace the `'...'` to `string` ?  i.e. `rules?: (RuleSetRule | string)[];`

Comment: If you wanted to construct your own type (not in line with Webpack), sure, you could do that.